# How to access a library's variable globally in NuxtJs app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to access the '$' variable of jQuery library globally without having to import $ every time on each component.

If you use CDN, you can simply access $ anywhere, so is it possible with 'npm install jquery'?

Like I don't want to do `'import $ from 'jquery'` for each component. Just want it accessible globally.